# jQuery PHP Handle input array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a structure like this:

```
<input type='text' name='value[$x]' class='kp'>
<input type='text' name='value[$y]' class='kp'>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( ".kp" ).keyup(function() {
      $('input[name^="value"]').each(function() {

      ***** HERE I WANT TO PRINT THE $x/$y VALUE INSIDE [] *****

      });
});
```

Like my code say, I wanna get the $x/$y variable of array.
(with .val(); function I get the string inside textbox)

Is there a way?
Thank you!

Comment: How did a question showing no effort whatsoever get 4 UV's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` inside `each` to access the current element and use regex on the `name` attribute to extract the value.

```
$(this)                       // Current element in the loop
    .attr('name')             // Get the `name` attribute value
    .match(/\[(.*?)]/)[1];    // Match string inside square brackets
```

1. `$(this).attr('name')` will get the `name` attribute value of the current input
2. `\[(.*?)]` will match anything inside the square brackets and add the string into first captured group
3. `[1]` on matched array will give the string inside square brackets.

```js
$(".kp").keyup(function() {
  $('input[name^="value"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('name').match(/\[(.*?)]/)[1]);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='value[11]' class='kp'>
<input type='text' name='value[22]' class='kp'>
```

Comment: Just because I like to use less jQuery, you can also do `this.name.match`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can access the current element in the callback with `$(this)`.

However i would not rely on regex to extract the integar value.

The each function receives two parameters, the 1st is the index, the 2nd is the element (equivalent to `this`).

If the values are sequential and start from 0, you can just use the 1st parameter to the each callback:

```
<input type='text' name='value[0]' class='kp'>
<input type='text' name='value[1]' class='kp'>


$( ".kp" ).keyup(function() {
  $('input[name^="value"]').each(function(index, element) {

      console.log(index);

  });
});
```

If not, i would suggest adding a data attribute to the html to contain the index:

```
<input type='text' name='value[13]' data-index='13' class='kp'>
<input type='text' name='value[106]' data-index='106' class='kp'>


$( ".kp" ).keyup(function() {
  $('input[name^="value"]').each(function(index, element) {

      console.log($(element).data('index'));

  });
});
```